# Terminating app due to uncaught exception

Tags: multithreading

When I run thee app than it crash also it show the error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',reasonNSCFDictionary length]: unrecognised selector sent to instance 0x60000006df80'.This app is for whether condition.I try to find the wether condition by using this application while the build no error but when I run this application it show the error unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000006df80'.So the problem is in the  func searchBarSearchButtonClicked (_ searchBar: UISearchBar) in this line. So please help me so I go for the next part.

```
        @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
        @IBOutlet weak var cityLbl: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var conditionLbl: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var degreeLbl: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var imgView: UIImageView!
        var degree: Int!
        var condition:String!
        var imgURL:String!
        var city:String!
        var exists: Bool = true
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
             searchBar.delegate = self
        }

        func searchBarSearchButtonClicked (_ searchBar: UISearchBar)
        {
         let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://api.apixu.com/v1/current.json?key=04e2f1e6e7db4897aee91005171207&q=\(searchBar.text!.replacingOccurrences(of:" ", with: "%20"))")!)
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, responce, error) in
                if error == nil{
                    do{
                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String: AnyObject]
                        if let current = json["current"] as? [String:AnyObject]{
                            if let temp = current["temp_c"] as? Int{
                             self.degree = temp
                            }
                            if let condition = current["condition"] as? [String:AnyObject]{
                             self.condition = condition["text"] as! String
                             let icon = condition["icon"] as! String
                             self.imgURL = "http:\(icon)"
                            }
                        }
                        if let location =  json["location"] as? [String:AnyObject]{
                            self.city = location["name"] as! String

                        }
                        if let _ = json["error"] {
                            self.exists = false
                        }
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            if self.exists{
                                self.degreeLbl.isHidden = false
                                self.cityLbl.isHidden = false
                                self.conditionLbl.isHidden = false
                                self.degreeLbl.text = "\(self.degree.description)°"
                                self.cityLbl.text = self.city
                                self.conditionLbl.text = self.condition
                            }else{
                                   self.degreeLbl.isHidden = true
                                   self.cityLbl.isHidden = true
                                   self.conditionLbl.isHidden = true
                                   self.cityLbl.text = "City does not Match"
                                   self.exists = true
                                   self.imgView.downloadImage(from: self.imgURL)
                            }
                        }

                    } catch let jsonError
                      {
                        print(jsonError.localizedDescription)
                       }


                    }
                }
              task.resume()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In info.plist The name of Main storyboard file base name it should be Main not empty